# Alexa: More than one smart home device name for one device

Tags: json, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I want to name my smart home device with three names, "My Thermostat", "Long Name's Thermostat" and "Short Name's Thermostat". I don't want to have three devices, because that would become confusing when I add more Thermostats with each two or three names. Is there any possibility to enter a synonym for a device?

I have this question also posted at [amazon's developer forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/106794/more-than-one-smart-home-device-name-for-one-devic.html).

Comment: Are you asking this as an Alexa user or an Alexa developer? The Alexa app has "groups" for at least some smart home devices, so you can have "the lights" "the reading lights" and "the bedroom lights" all be a group of one or more lights, and ask Alexa to turn them (it) on/off (even it there's only one controller in the group -- a group of one acts as an alias for that one).  I don't know if this applies to thermostats, but it's also not fully clear exactly what you are asking or trying to accomplish, and from what perspective.

Comment: I'm asking this as an developer. I'm currently testing my own skill. Alexa's "groups" aren't helping me, because when I try to set the temperature to this group, Alexa responses that she couldn't find "My Thermostat".